# should I convert a H1 into a button to let it call a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, tags

I created a dynamic webpage which is a search form basically.
Several functions are called according to which button is clicked, and so finally the webpage ends up with several text fields filled up.

I want to add a function `empty()` to let me empty all the text fields and go back to the initial situation (when the webpage is opened, before having clicked on any button and having called any function).
I want to call such a function whenever the user clicks on the title of the page, which is a `<h1>` element for the sake of simplicity.

I wonder if I should substitute the `<h1>` element with a button and then call the function `empty()` on the `.click()` event as in the following:

```
function main() {        

    $("#idOfTheButton").on('click', functionEmpty);      

};
```

...or if I may keep the `<h1>` element and add such a function to it somehow after having assigned an ID?

...Or alternatively, should I convert the `<h1>` into an `<img>` and add a `<href>` or the function `empty()` somehow?

Which is the best practice to call a function by clicking on the title of a webpage?

- - - - E D I T - - - -

I kept the `<h1>` element, assigned the ID `TitleH1` to it and added the following function to `main()`:

```
function main() {

    $('#TitleH1').on('click', window.location.reload() );

};
```

The problem now is that the page is reloading continuously all the time, without clicking the `<h1>` ...

- - - - EDIT 2 - - - - -

I made the method `window.location.reload` into a function (thanks to @MHD for the suggestion) and now it's working. The correct snippet is the following:

```
function main() {    

    $('#TitleH1').on('click', ()=> window.location.reload());

    }
```

Comment: Best based on what criteria? Also, I'd just wrap it in an `<a>` and attach the click there.

Comment: I mean you can do literally any of the above options you want. Onclick on the h1 element, convert it to a button, or an image etc. You need to better define your criteria for what constitutes "best".

Comment: Sort of depends why clicking the title should do that, but in the absence of any other information, a button is the accessible choice, yes. A simple `h1` with a click listener can’t be e.g. keyboard-activated without extra work. (Remember `type="reset"` exists too.)

Comment: You *might* be better off asking this on [ux.se], but you should read their [help center](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help) first to ensure it's on topic.

Comment: I kept the '<h1>' and added the function 'window.location.reload()'  but the page is reloading all the time now (I added it to the Question)

Comment: You're calling `window.location.reload()`, use a reference to the method instead of invoking it.

Comment: Make it into a function: `$('#TitleH1').on('click', () => window.location.reload());`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to integrate your edits into your final question form, rather than the distracting bullet/title form you're using now. Interested parties can look at [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56755760/revisions) if they need to see how the question changed.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I already edited my Question by adding the edits mentioned above

Answer (score 2):

A header is not a button, a button is not a header. Your visual design sounds strange to me, it leads me to think your user experience might be suffering.

If you use an `A`-element, then you are creating a link with an `href` attribute. Its intent is navigation. So your initial thought to make it a `button` makes the best sense. Do not abuse the `A`-element if you want it to be a button; just use a button.

What I would suggest: Keep your `H1` element as-is. Add a reset-button to your form, label it "reset". Then `onClick` you can fire the reset function, although an `<input type="reset" />` button automatically does that for you, if you're inside a `form`.